# How to Produce a Footnote Like This for Some Lyric Sheets

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes, memoir, alignment, definition

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{verse}
\begin{bfseries}
\hskip -12pt* A special footnote \\[1pt]
\hskip 15pt To be put \textit{this way;} \\[1pt]
(Not the way footnotes \\[1pt]
\hskip 15pt Are usually displayed.)
\end{bfseries}
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I define a new kind of footnote that when invoked, displays the footnotemark as shown, with the corresponding text at the bottom of the page in the usual way? I would like to be able to such a thing for some lyric sheets that I designed and currently use.

*Remark:* I would still like to retain the `\footnote` command for producing footnotes in the usual way.

Thank you.

Comment: Do I get it right, your code only shows how the intended footnote should be typeset? If so, can you please add a second simple example showing your intended use? Thanks // How important is the documentclass for this?

Comment: @MS-SPO Effectively, I would like to be able to take the code as given, and type, say, `\footnoteB A special footnote`---and have the footnotemark appear as shown. It is really a matter of adding some automatic spacing to the right of the footnotemark. I can be done manually; say, `\footnote{text} \hskip 2pt`, but I am hoping to have this done automatically by defining a new kind of footnote.

Comment: @MS-SPO Oh, the documentclass is not important. In reality, I am using `article`. I only chose `memoir` so I could exceed the 12pt fontsize limit for the MWE..

Comment: Ok. Do you need to rely on footnote counters?

Comment: @MS-SPO I do not have to rely on footnote counters; so, an asterisk, say, with `\footnoteB` and another  `asterisk` with ordinary `\footnote` is perfectly fine. This is because I don't anticipate too many footnotes in any particular lyric sheet. The special footnote is likely to be the only one. I intend to use it to indicate a change in the tempo of which a particular verse is to be sung.

Comment: What about putting the footnote mark in the margin, as in `\newcommand{\footnoteB}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\textsuperscript{*}\hspace*{2pt}}}`?

Comment: @Werner Thank you for the suggestion. Everything seems to be fine (or adjustably fine) except---`\footnoteB` does not produce a footnote. When I type, for example, "\footnoteB{This is a special footnote.}A special footnote \\[1pt]", what gets produced is "* This is a special footnote.A special footnote"

Comment: @Werner Is it possible to have `\footnoteB` actually produce a footnote? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An approach could be via package `footmisc`, which documentation could be improved in my view.

Just as a start I simply copied your code as footnote-text. It's not perfect, as you still have to replace the symbol in the footnote, somehow. (And probably all `%` are missing at the end of those lines)

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

Example\footnote{\begin{bfseries}
\hskip -12pt* A special footnote \\[1pt]
\hskip 15pt To be put \textit{this way;} \\[1pt]
(Not the way footnotes \\[1pt]
\hskip 15pt Are usually displayed.)
\end{bfseries}}:

\begin{verse}
    A dozen, a gross, and a score\\
    Plus three times the square root of four\\
    Divided by seven\\
    Plus five times eleven\\
    Is nine squared and not a bit more.
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post this; but perhaps, it was not clear what I was asking for. I don't want to make a footnote out of "A special footnote ... usually displayed.)" But rather, I want to keep it as text with a footnotemark (asterisk) appearing  to the left of the first line, as displayed. --- So, that I could type a new footnote command, say `\footnoteB` to the left of "A special footnote ... " and what I have displayed above appears.

Comment: So you want a variation of \marginpar?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that specifically; but it should be OK if the new footnotemark was inserted in the left-hand margin of the page---just so the output resembles the output of the MWE. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in,paperheight=3in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\newcommand\footnoteB[1]{\hskip -15pt\footnote{#1}{\hspace*{8pt}}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{verse}
\begin{bfseries}
\footnoteB{This is a special footnote.}A special footnote \\[1pt]
\hskip 15pt To be put \textit{this way;} \\[1pt]
(Not the way footnotes \\[1pt]
\hskip 15pt Are usually displayed.)
\end{bfseries}
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

The `\hskip` and `\hspace*` values can be adjusted to suit.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Rather use something like this: `\newcommand\footnoteB[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\footnotemark\hspace*{8pt}}\footnotetext{#1}}` It's independent of the width of the footnote mark since everything is set in a zero-width box.

Comment: Thank you @Werner.